# What would the parametric equations be for an object moving along a 2D curve at a constant speed?

Tags: kinematics

Please excuse my ignorance or poorly worded question (this is my first one), but I am wondering how to go about **deriving the parametric equations for the x and y motion of an object traveling along a 2D path (like $y = x^3$) at a constant speed**.
Here are the things I "think" I know:
$$s = \sqrt {\frac{dy}{dt}^2 + \frac{dx}{dt}^2}$$
where $s$ is some constant representing the speed of the object.
Also, the path should mean that: $$y(t) = x(t)^3$$

My Failed Attempt: From here, taking the derivative of both sides with respect to t should lead to: $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 3x^2\frac{dx}{dt}$$
After this, I tried substituting this back into the initial equation:
$$s = \sqrt {\left(3x^2\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{dx}{dt}^2}$$
$$s = \sqrt {9x^4\frac{dx}{dt}^2 + \frac{dx}{dt}^2}$$
$$s = \sqrt {\left(9x^4+1\right)\frac{dx}{dt}^2}$$
$$s^2 = \left(9x^4+1\right)\frac{dx}{dt}^2$$
$$\frac{s}{\sqrt {9x^4+1}}= \frac{dx}{dt}$$
Is this even separable? Is the equation for motion even along a simple cubic function really this complicated? This is just $x$, $y$ is obviously more disgusting, can that be done too? What am I missing in this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems better suited for mathematics, as you are just asking about how to solve a differential equation at this point. Also why wouldn't it be separable? You have $\sqrt{9x^4+1}\,\text dx=s\,\text dt$.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Is this the correct physical interpretation of the problem though? I am very new to physics (first year in high school), so I don't really know what I am doing in general.

Comment: What physical interpretation? I just see a bunch of equations. Note that "check my work" questions are off topic here.

Comment: Your general reasoning looks right to me. Just gotta solve that differential equation to get $x(t)$.